# Lobo browser integrated in my swing application,but shows error messages when executed

Tags: java, swing, lobo

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import org.lobobrowser.gui.*;
import org.lobobrowser.main.PlatformInit;

public class BrowserPanelTest extends JFrame {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    PlatformInit.getInstance().initLogging(false);


    PlatformInit.getInstance().init(false, false);

    // Create frame with a specific size.
    JFrame frame = new BrowserPanelTest();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public BrowserPanelTest() throws Exception {
    this.setTitle("Lobo Demo");
    final BrowserPanel bp = new BrowserPanel();
    bp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new    EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED), "Embedded browser"));
    bp.navigate("http://lobobrowser.org/browser/home.jsp");
    this.getContentPane().add(bp);

    this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            // This needs to be called in order
            // to inform extensions about the
            // window closing.
            bp.windowClosing();
        }
    });
    }
    }
```

I intended to create a web browser with CSS and JavaScript enabled.I downloaded Lobo Browser,added the jar files to the classpath of my project,and then,visited their website to know how to use it.I got an example over there and tested it.But,I am coming across a pile of error messages,for instance:-

```
Oct 24, 2014 9:33:08 PM org.lobobrowser.primary.ext.ExtensionImpl showError
WARNING: showError(): An error occurred trying to process document   http://lobobrowser.org/browser/home.jsp
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface sun.font.FontManager, but class was expected
 at org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.createFont(FontFactory.java:210)
 at org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.createFont_Impl(FontFactory.java:180)
 at org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.createFont(FontFactory.java:127)
 at org.lobobrowser.util.gui.FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.java:98)
 at org.lobobrowser.html.style.StyleSheetRenderState.<clinit>(StyleSheetRenderState.java:43)
 at org.lobobrowser.html.domimpl.NodeImpl.<clinit>(NodeImpl.java:39)
 at org.lobobrowser.html.parser.DocumentBuilderImpl.createDocument(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:143)
at  org.lobobrowser.primary.clientlets.html.HtmlClientlet.processImpl(HtmlClientlet.java:150)
at org.lobobrowser.primary.clientlets.html.HtmlClientlet.process(HtmlClientlet.java:79)
at  org.lobobrowser.request.ClientletRequestHandler.processResponse(ClientletRequestHandler.java:115)
at org.lobobrowser.request.RequestEngine.processHandler(RequestEngine.java:856)
at org.lobobrowser.request.RequestEngine.access$1(RequestEngine.java:713)
at org.lobobrowser.request.RequestEngine$RequestHandlerTask$1.run(RequestEngine.java:1026)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lobobrowser.request.RequestEngine$RequestHandlerTask.run(RequestEngine.java:1033)
at org.lobobrowser.util.SimpleThreadPool$ThreadRunnable.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:127)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lobobrowser.html.domimpl.HTMLDocumentImpl
at  org.lobobrowser.html.parser.DocumentBuilderImpl.createDocument(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:143)
 at org.lobobrowser.html.parser.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:97)
 at org.lobobrowser.html.gui.HtmlPanel.setHtml(HtmlPanel.java:414)
 at org.lobobrowser.primary.ext.ExtensionImpl.getErrorComponent(ExtensionImpl.java:95)
 at org.lobobrowser.primary.ext.ExtensionImpl.showError(ExtensionImpl.java:87)
 at org.lobobrowser.primary.ext.ExtensionImpl$1.errorOcurred(ExtensionImpl.java:49)
 at org.lobobrowser.main.Extension$NavigatorErrorEventDispatch.dispatchEvent(Extension.java:532)
at org.lobobrowser.util.EventDispatch2.fireEvent(EventDispatch2.java:71)
at org.lobobrowser.main.Extension.handleError(Extension.java:318)
at org.lobobrowser.main.ExtensionManager$3.run(ExtensionManager.java:304)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Oct 24, 2014 9:33:23 PM org.lobobrowser.store.CacheManager run
SEVERE: run()
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.lobobrowser.store.CacheManager.populateCacheStoreInfo(CacheManager.java:283)
at org.lobobrowser.store.CacheManager.getCacheStoreInfo(CacheManager.java:277)
at org.lobobrowser.store.CacheManager.sweepCache(CacheManager.java:237)
at org.lobobrowser.store.CacheManager.run(CacheManager.java:219)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Can enybody get me out of this cauldron of black waters?

Comment: Add `lobos.jar` to your runtime classpath

Comment: It seems this browser uses internal classes of the Sun JDK that they should not use, and that are not compatible with the classes in your version of the JDK. So, either you're using a too recent JDK, or you're using a too old one. Try to discover which JDK lobos is compatible with, from their documentation. But I would be scared by the quelity of this product if I were you.

Comment: I am using JDK 7.0.From their documentation,I came to know that Lobo browser is pretty much compatible with this JDK version.